# In inter-app audio, how can I get the bpm / tempo of the host sequencer?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am implementing inter-app audio into my drum machine.

If would be great of course, if it would play in sync with the host app.
How can I read out the tempo of the host app/node, for example garage band?

And - I guess, there could be occur some latency between my app and the host app.
Any suggestion how to handle this?

Thank you,
Oliver

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the solution:

```
        // BPM
        Float64 isCurrentBeat; // = self.currentBeat;
        Float64 isCurrentBPM; // = self.currentBPM;
        HostCallback_GetBeatAndTempo beat = callBackInfo->beatAndTempoProc(hostUserData,
                                                                           &isCurrentBeat,
                                                                           &isCurrentBPM);
        if (beat == noErr) {
            if (self.currentBPM != isCurrentBPM) {
                NSLog(@"%@ - currentBPM: %f currentBeat: %f \r", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.currentBPM, isCurrentBPM);
                [[OGAudioController defaultAudio] setBPMto:isCurrentBPM];
            }
            //NSLog(@"%@ - currentBPM: %f currentBeat: %f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.currentBPM, isCurrentBPM);
            self.currentBPM = isCurrentBPM;
            self.currentBeat = isCurrentBeat;
        }
```